# iOS Firebase token fetching issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I am receiving this issue when fetching token via iOS out of sudden. We managed to get this error message via debugging as a lot of device cannot receive push notification. Is this a firebase server issue or provisioning profile configuration issue?

```
[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.installations Code=2 "Too many server requests."
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem was in the deprecated Firebase API. If you use `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID` method for fetching token, then you need change it to `Installations.installations().installationID { (token, error) in }` from `FirebaseInstallations` framework.